# How do I check what kernel options were compiled without looking at /boot/config-*

Tags: linux, kernel

How do I check what options are compiled into a Linux kernel without looking at `/boot/config-*` and if I don't have access to the `/boot/config-*` file that's left over?

Comment: Similar on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Unless your kernel was built with `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC`, which would make the config available in `/proc` as sysadmin1138 mentioned above, you're pretty much out of luck.  Debian and RH based kernel packages do, however, generally install a `config-$version` file in `/boot`.  So unless it's a custom kernel, it should be available there.

Answer (score 34):

I believe /proc/config.gz contains the .config file the kernel was compiled with.

Comment: That's only available if `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC` was set when the kernel was built.  Doesn't seem to be there by default on RHEL or Ubuntu.

Comment: As of writing, this is enabled by default on Arch :)

Comment: to read (or grep) the current settings from config.gz you can unzip it with `$cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip > mykernel.conf` as suggested by [Jarl on superuser.com](http://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system).

Comment: It is the case on Arch Linux as `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=y`.

Comment: @xaa Or you can use the single command alternatives `zcat` or `zless`, the latter of which is more convenient as it is a pager which allows you to scroll and search as well.